# Rails create action with multiple belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, strong-parameters

Trying to figure out a better way of assigning a review it's associated models.

I have the following classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :restaurant
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Pretty straightforward stuff. A review must have a restaurant and a user. My create action looks like this:

```
def create
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
    @review = @restaurant.reviews.build(review_params)
    @review.user = current_user

    if @review.save
        redirect_to @restaurant
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
  def review_params
    params.require(:review).permit(:content)
  end
```

Currently I build the review for the restaurant and then I assign the review's user to the current user.

This all works fine but is there a cleaner way to build the associations? 
Is there a way to add additional arguments to the build method alongside the strong params?

I looked at accepts_nested_attributes_for but I couldn't get it to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `merge` in the `review_params` like below

```
def review_params
  params.require(:review).permit(:content).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

so that you can erase this line `@review.user = current_user` in the `create` method

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In your form, you can put a hidden field with the `user_id` that you want to assign:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: @user.id %>
```

Then, add it to your `review_params`:

```
params.require(:review).permit(:content, :user_id)
```

Comment: I thought about using hidden fields, but I didn't want to include sensitive info like a user's id. It's my understanding that a malicious user could still change the value. Is there an other alternative?

Comment: Well, you would only be showing the `user_id` on the form page. And only to the logged in user. So I couldn't see your `user_id` unless I was already logged in as you. And yes, I could change the value of the hidden field, but I would have to either guess at an id or already know one.

Comment: Another way is to have a field in the user model for a super secret passcode (say, a random 10-20 digit number). It wouldn't be sequential like Active Record ids, so it would be harder for someone to guess.